# how to find total number of dropped packets from android device in ad-hoc network

Tags: android, networking, tcp, adhoc

I am writing an app for android. i'm using manet manger and file transfer apps.

in my app, i want to setup ad-hoc network. I manage to get it working and it is running olsrd as routing protocol. 
but i'm facing a problem. I need to find out how many packet that i send my neighbors are being dropped. I need to know this in order to find out which neighbors to trust.